# Change dropdown quantity to 10, 20, 30

Tags: magento-1.9, product, drop-downs

I'm trying to change the **dropdown quantity** in this theme -

currently it shows a **dropdown menu** of 1 to 10+ - I'd like it to only show 10, 20, 30 etc so the user can only select 3 options (10, 20, 30)

How would I go about changing both below to achieve this?

**Product Page - catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Intenso Premium Theme
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     intenso_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014-2015 Itactica (http://www.itactica.com)
 * @license     http://getintenso.com/license
 */
?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $productData = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product); ?>
<?php
    $attributeOptions = array();
    if ($_product->isConfigurable()) {
        $productAttributeOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
        foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
            $attributeOptions[] = $productAttribute['label'];
        }
    }
?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable() && Mage::getStoreConfig('intenso/product_page/product_show_add_to_cart', Mage::app()->getStore())): ?>
<div class="buybox bg-box center">
    <?php if ($attributeOptions): ?>
        <p><?php echo $this->__('To buy, select <strong>%s</strong>',implode($this->__(' and '), $attributeOptions)) ?></p>
        <p class="small"><?php echo $this->__('Choose from options to the left') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <p><?php echo $this->__('To buy, select quantities to the left') ?></strong></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <div class="qty-wrapper">
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
            <span id="qty-wrapper">
            <?php if ($this->helper('itactica_intenso')->qtyFieldIsDropdown() && ($this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1) < 10): ?>
                <select name="qty" id="qty" class="simulate-change">
                <?php for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if (($this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1) == $i): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
                <option value="10">10+</option>
                </select>
                <script>
                $("qty").observe('change', function(){
                    if ($(this).getValue() == 10) {
                        $("qty-wrapper").update('<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" maxlength="10" class="qty-input-text" />');
                    }
                });
                </script>
            <?php else: ?>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" class="qty-input-text" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Checkout - checkout/cart/item/default.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Intenso Premium Theme
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     intenso_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Itactica (http://www.itactica.com)
 * @license     http://getintenso.com/license
 */
?>
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?></td>
    <td>
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image for-small"><?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?>
        <h2 class="product-name">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </h2>
        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <dl class="item-options clearfix">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
            <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">* <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item parameters') ?>" class="btn-edit"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        <?php endif ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?></a>
    </td>
    <?php /*if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
    <td class="a-center">
        <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getMoveFromCartUrl($_item->getId()); ?>" class="link-wishlist use-ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Move'); ?></a>
        <?php endif ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif*/ ?>
    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
        <td class="a-right"<?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?> colspan="2"<?php endif; ?>>
            <span class="cart-price">
                <span class="cart-msrp-unit"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>
                <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                <a id="<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>" href="#" class="map-help-link" data-reveal-id="map-popup"><?php echo $this->__("What's this?"); ?></a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    Catalog.Map.addHelpLink($('<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>'), "<?php echo $this->__('What\'s this?') ?>");
                </script>
            </span>
        </td>
    <?php else: ?>

        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td class="a-right">
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?><!-- inclusive price starts here -->
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td>
            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td id="qty-wrapper-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="qty-wrapper">
        <?php if ($this->getQty() < 10): ?>
            <select name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" id="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" class="simulate-change">
                <?php for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"<?php if ($this->getQty() == $i): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $i ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
                <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var updateButton<?php echo $_item->getId() ?> = true;
                $("cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]").observe('change', function(){
                    if ($(this).getValue() == 10) {
                        $("qty-wrapper-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>").update('<input type="number" min="0" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" maxlength="10" class="input-text qty" />');
                    }
                    if (updateButton<?php echo $_item->getId() ?> && $(this).getValue() != <?php echo $this->getQty() ?>) {
                        $("qty-wrapper-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>").insert('<button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-update tiny"><span><?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?></span></button>');
                        updateButton<?php echo $_item->getId() ?> = false;
                    }
                    if ($(this).getValue() == <?php echo $this->getQty() ?> && !updateButton<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>) {
                        $("qty-wrapper-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>").select('.button').first().remove();
                        updateButton<?php echo $_item->getId() ?> = true;
                    }
                });
            </script>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" id="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="3" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var updateButton<?php echo $_item->getId() ?> = true;
                $("cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]").observe('keyup', function(){
                    if (($(this).getValue() < <?php echo $this->getQty() ?> || $(this).getValue() > <?php echo $this->getQty() ?>) && $(this).getValue() != '') {
                        if (!$("qty-wrapper-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>").select('.button').first()) {
                            $("qty-wrapper-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>").insert('<button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-update tiny"><span><?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?></span></button>');
                        }
                        updateButton<?php echo $_item->getId() ?> = false;
                    } else {
                        if ($("qty-wrapper-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>").select('.button').first()) {
                            $("qty-wrapper-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>").select('.button').first().remove();
                            updateButton<?php echo $_item->getId() ?> = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear which dropdown you are talking about in your question. But I can see a `select` element which you had been talking about in your question. So please replace this part of code :

```
<select name="qty" id="qty" class="simulate-change">
            <?php for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if (($this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1) == $i): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select>
```

with this code:

```
<select name="qty" id="qty" class="simulate-change">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

in `addtocart.phtml` file

Comment: Also change it in **checkout/cart/item/default.phtml**